# MS office COM add-ins functionality and dll

Tags: dll, com, office-interop

I am very new to development on MS platform and hence I have some issues in understanding the concepts of dll's and how they are used by applications. I have quite extensive experience with Java and will try to compare them in order to understand the functionality even more.

From what I understand, dll's are complied c++/c#/mfc code. Its almost equivalent to .class from Java (Except class files can be decompiled). dll's can be imported in any other source files as a library and so can class files.

Now what I want to know is when we use this dll, is there just once instance of dll that will be shared by multiple instances of application using it or each and every application have its on instance of the dll. I assume it would be the latter as it makes more sense since MS development is completely object oriented.

One prime example of this can be running COM add-ins in any office application. We can have several open instances of excel application with different workbooks. So does each workbook have its own instance of the add-in (which is in form of a dll file) or there is just one instance which is started when excel first loaded and it is shared with all the open workbooks until the last one closes.

If they are not shared, is there any way to share some methods between time (like making static methods and variables in Java)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comprehensive explanation of **Windows DLLs**. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065

Regarding instances, I believe it is the latter as you suggested i.e. 1 instance per process, which in case of COM add-ins would be each running instance.

See this paragraph from the article.

> When multiple programs use the same library of functions, a DLL can
>   reduce the duplication of code that is loaded on the disk and in
>   physical memory. This can greatly influence the performance of not
>   just the program that is running in the foreground, but also other
>   programs that are running on the Windows operating system.